# In Java is there any way to tell if a class is a simple 'Java' class?

Tags: java, reflection

I'm using reflection to read through some class objects I've created and using recursion to trace down through the entire object tree.

The problem I have is that when I have a 'Field' I need to know if it's a simple attribute or another complex object. The former can just be processed immediately, but the latter I need to dig into and call the recursive method again. My code is something like this :

```
recurse(Object o) {
    Class clazz = o.getClass();
    for (Field f : clazz.getDeclaredFields() ) {
        fieldClass = f.getType();

        // Heres the broken part
        if ( !ClassUtils.isPrimitiveOrWrapper(fieldClass) ) {
            recurse(f.get(o));
        }
        else {
            // Process simple attribute
        }
    }
}
```

I thought this would work, but then I found that String is not a 'PrimitiveOrWrapper'.... then I found that Date isn't either... then I found that BigDecimal isn't either...

Is there really NO class or utility package that can handle this request? All I want is to know if a Class is an internal / native / plain / simple / basic Java class or a complex object that I've written. This shouldn't be hard.

I believe my choices are :

1. Trial and error to list them all individually - hoping that two years
   in the future I don't add another attribute of a type I haven't used
   before (Yuck!)
2. See if the class name begins with the string **java.** (double Yuck!)

Please tell me I missed a nice utility class/method somewhere.

Comment: There is no such notion of "simple" Java classes.  Neither `String`, `Date`, nor `BigDecimal` are "simple" in any sense of the word.

Comment: Just a short question. If you process the "simple" attribute you need to know what class it is? Or are you writing something for serialization? Then you could use marker interfaces. Otherwise you might run into problems with every new java versions if new classes are added or stuff like that.

Comment: So, you want to know if a class is something that you've written as opposed to something that comes with the core libraries  such as `java.lang.String` or `java.util.Date`  What about other libraries classes are they also considered "simple" ( e.g. `org.apache.log4j.Logger` ) or are they a "complex object"?

You may opt for having your objects tagged with an annotation:

```@Complex public MyClass { int x; }```

Comment: dimo - by 'simple' I mean a field that represents a single attribute value - String, Integer, BigDecimal, as opposed to a complex object that holds many 'simple' fields in addition to references to other complex objects. Pinkie & Oscar - Yes, I am serializing a Bean object into a URL parameter string, so these objects are just fields with getters/setters, but they may have sub-objects that also need to be traced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no single API call that will tell you whether the object is internal or not.

You can however use the following methods:

```
isPrimitive
isArray
getPackage
```

The first one is fairly straight forward.  The second, `isArray` is needed as there is a special method which will return the component type of the array.  Lastly `getPackage` can be used to answer the question, is this object part of the JDK family or not.  All public Java API packages start with `java.` or `javax.` and private Java APIs start with `sun.`.

Comment: This isnt the answer I was hoping for, but I guess its the correct answer. I still thing some library should have something like this.